# Magento Magmi not updating products through Magmi CLI

Tags: php, magento, csv, magmi

I need to setup the cron job to update the prices of the products daily. So I tried like this in command prompt first,

```
php magmi.cli.php -profile=default -mode=update -CSV:filename="/path/magento/var/import/Price.csv"
```

It is showing the following errors:

```
fopen(/var/www/html/magento/magmi/state/progress.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /path/magento/magmi/inc/magmi_loggers.php on line 20

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'CANNOT WRITE PROGRESS FILE ' in /path/magento/magmi/inc/magmi_loggers.php:23
```

Comment: it seems like you dont have permissions to read or write to the files in to magmi folder.Assign the proper permissions to the directory and hope that will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

It's permission issue:

This folder /var/www/html/magento/magmi/state/ and all it's contents should be given either 777 or 755 permission.

Run the following command:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/magento/magmi/state/
```

If you still have some problems then try

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/html/magento/magmi/state/
```

Comment: Thank you,it worked.Now it is showing fgetcsv():enclosure must be a single character in magim/inc/magmi_csvreader.php on line 195 error.Same file working fine in UI mode,do you have any idea?

Comment: I believe you have to set the enclosure and delimiters in the configuration page of magmi... Set the enclosure and delimiters to the type (' or ") you're using. Then, magmi should parse the csv.